# Why am I not able to deploy hyperledger composer project

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am trying to deploy my first hyperledger composer playground project. I am following this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JQMh_DQ6wXc

I am stuck at code of JS file.

I am getting following error:

> Error: SyntaxError: Failed to parse null: Malformed JSDoc comment: *
>   @param (org.acme.testproject.Hello) hello @transaction

my JS file code:

```
/**
*New Script File
*/

/**
@param (org.acme.testproject.Hello) hello
@transaction
*/

function hello (hello){
console.log("Hello" + hello.test.message);
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace this sentence `@param (org.acme.testproject.Hello) hello` with `@param {org.acme.testproject.Hello} hello` this.

Comment: Thanks that worked like a charm. However I am having further issue when submitting transaction after creating asset. I am getting following error.

Error: Could not find any functions to execute for transaction org.acme.testproject.Hello#a00bc703-5014-464f-9b47-1ee2490efb07

Comment: Please attach your asset and transaction values which you added.